# Instagram Share Extension returning error message when sharing image via local url

Tags: swift, uikit, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm having an issue with sharing an image to Instagram via the iOS share sheet. I need to share the image through a URL to a local file, since I want the image to be named a certain way when shared, and that's the only way I found I could do that. The code is:

```
//This saves the image into the local temp directory and returns the file url
saveImageForSharing(image: image!) {(tempUrl) in
    if tempUrl != nil {
        let objectsToShare = [tempUrl!]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When the UIActivityViewController comes up you can share the image successfully to ALL the services available (including Facebook, email, Twitter etc), EXCEPT Instagram. When sharing to Instagram, the following error pops up:
[image: Instagram Error]

Setting a completion handler for the UIActivityViewController's completionWithItemsHandler, the 'success' parameter is returned as false, but the error object is nil, so there's no information  to be had about what went wrong.

When sharing a UIImage directly, there's no problem. Also when saving to a different URL or when changing the file name.

Any ideas what could be happening here, or how I can share an image successfully while also setting the item's name?

Edit: I've also encountered this problem when trying to share a video through its url. The video is stored simply in the Photos library, and I can't get Instagram to accept it, even though it shared perfectly well when sharing from the Photos app! Also, I'm getting a message in the output console that says "Failed to ssue sandbox token for URL:". Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this same issue but for a video file and it's driving me nuts. Just a heads up for images though, if I pass the `UIActivityViewController` a data object instead of a url, it works for me. I was also able to make it work with images if I created a custom class that conforms to `UIActivityItemSource`. If you want, I can post the item source subclass and you can give it a try.

Comment: I am also having this issue with video files! Did the trick with the custom class work with videos? If so, I'd love to see the code! Thanks!

Comment: I've tried using a data object but then IG doesn't appear in the share sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and see if it resolves your issue.

```swift
class ShareItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    private let url: URL
    private let title: String

    init(url: URL, title: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        url
    }

    func activityViewController(_: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType _: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        url
    }

    func activityViewController(_: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType _: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        title
    }

    func activityViewController(_: UIActivityViewController, dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType _: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]).typeIdentifier) ?? ""
    }

    func activityViewController(_: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType _: UIActivity.ActivityType?, suggestedSize _: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.absoluteString)
    }

    func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()

        metadata.originalURL = url
        metadata.url = url
        metadata.title = title

        return metadata
    }
}
```

You would then pass an instance of `ShareItem` to the `UIActivityViewController` instead of your tempUrl.

```swift
// This saves the image into the local temp directory and returns the file url
saveImageForSharing(image: image!) { tempUrl in
    guard let url = tempUrl else {
        return
    }

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [
            ShareItem(url: url, title: "Your Title")
        ],
        applicationActivities: nil
    )

    self.present(
        activityVC,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: I've tried this for the problem with sharing a video and it didn't work.... I do get a message saying "Failed to ssue sandbox token for URL:", with the info: Cannot issue a sandbox extension for file [file URL]: Operation not permitted. Any ideas what this means?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's up to Instagram API.

If you try to share `let objectsToShare = [tempUrl!, tempUrl!]` it will work for some reason, probably because of some mess on Instagram's side. It's a very hacky solution.

EDIT: So with Instagram version 171.0 this issue is fixed. It's working but it's very ugly, you can't choose between story and feed, and you can't edit photo.

Comment: Returning the array isn't working for me :( (Though I'm returning that from my own UIActivityItemProvider))

Comment: I can't get this to work with a video URL now... same problem. I tried this array and it didn't work unfortunately... I have IG version 173 now.